# windows 10 (1809) installed from iso- autoactivated to home

Tags: windows, windows-10

I downloaded windows from Microsoft website and the ISO contained both home and pro versions but somehow it is auto activated to the home version. I was hoping to use an un-activated pro version. What is the simplest way I can do that without  breaking any law or downloading shady stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade Home to Pro using a Pro product key. Potential sources of keys are Google, [Microsoft docs (KMS keys)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/kmsclientkeys#windows-10-all-supported-semi-annual-channel-versions). If you use invalid Pro key (inactivable), just disconnect internet, Windows will skip verification and upgrade to Pro, but it will not activate.